# best practice how to schedule symfony2 action

Tags: symfony, cron, scheduled-tasks

My application based on symfony2 has to do some standalone jobs at differents moments and differents frequencies. For exemple, sending newsletter, editing report ...

I want to be able to add/edit each task from the application
My task would be very close to cron jobs and will consist to call a specific url.

### From my point of view :

I think about creating a cron job that launch a script every half hour, or ten minutes. this script only do a curl command witch get a docronjob action. This docronjobaction is inside symfony and is responsible to get all the task and launch the one it has to.

### My questions are :

- Is there a cleaner way to achive that ?
- Inside the docronaction how do I launch others action ?
- How do I manage to set the time limit to 0 for an entire controller ?
- Does a bundle doing this allready exist ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds you are storing your schedule of tasks in the database. No problem. For every different type of task (eg. sending newsletter, save reports) create a service, which does the task. Then add to this services a tag (like twig.extension, [but your own](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html)), so you have something like a TaskChain, which knows all the tasks.

For executing [create a console command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html), which retrieves the schedule from the database, loads the TaskChain, and executes the tasks. This console command can be simply called from a cronjob without exposing it to the web. In fact your are calling this command via the php-cli and not from a browser, the standard time limit is unlimited. No controllers should be involved for executing.

This should be all organized in an extra TaskBundle.

Comment: It sounds mutch cleaner :D ! But what do you mean by : "For every different type if task create a service" ? as you said my tasks are in databases and I want to be able to add a new one without touching the code, so I can't create a service for each task. I understood that I should create a taskService for each "type" of task. What would be a type for exemple ?

Comment: Sorry, typo. **o**f type. You need some code, for every type of task. Sending Newsletters (or more basic emails) should be a task service. Or creating reports, need also some specific and generic code. This has to be done. Configuring the tasks can be placed in the database.

Comment: Thanks @Pazi for your advice. I will try to implement your solution as it is better than mine! (I'll left the post unsolve for couple of days to see if there is others ideas out there)

Comment: Kk. Maybe there are some other ways too. That's only one possible way, as I do this in some of my applications, where database flexible configuration meets different tasks in code.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [this blog](http://devvness.blogspot.com/2013/11/ejecutar-tareas-programadas-en-symfony.html) in order to do what you want. You could then use cron or someother program to trigger the action.

In summary:

First of all, you need to create a symfony command that executes the functionality that you wish. For that, create a folder named "Command" in our Bundle at the same level that we have "Controller or Resources" and put a name in our class. The name has to end with "Command" or it won't work. Let's call it "MyCommand".

```
    <?php
    namespace Devvness\DevvnessBundle\Command;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

    class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
    {


 protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('devvness:my_command')
            ->setDescription('Descripción de lo que hace el comando')
            ->addArgument('my_argument', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Explicamos el significado del argumento');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        // Hacemos lo que sea
        $output->writeln('Hola mundo');
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it by executing on cmd or console:

```
php app/console devness:mycommand
```

or

```
php app/console devness:mycommand --my_argument=valor
```

Then you need to scheduled the task with cron for Unix or something like that by editing the cron file

```
* * * * * php /root/absolute/for/symfony/project/app/console devness:mycommand --myargument=valor
```

Answer (score 3):

I had very similar needs (that's why i found this old topic) while working on an application with a lot of commands to manage.

I finally made my own bundle to manage execution and queuing of mutiple symfony command (scheduled tasks stored via Doctrine).

Here is the Git repository  : [CommandSchedulerBundle](https://github.com/J-Mose/CommandSchedulerBundle)

I hope it will help someone.

Best regards

Comment: Thank you very much for you contribution, I'll have a closer look to your bundle

Comment: @J-Mose Your bundle works awesome. But I am going mad with some issues. Is it possible to get the id from DB of the current scheduler execution ? Also scheduler couldn't write logs, its giving me below error
`php.INFO: Not quoting a scalar starting with the "%" indicator character is deprecated since Symfony 3.1 and will throw a ParseException in 4.0`

Answer (score 1):

Try **[JmsJobQueue](https://packagist.org/packages/jms/job-queue-bundle)** ([documentation](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle))  which can handle :

- List item
- Running Symfony console commands,
- Reading Jobs from database,
- Job scheduling,
- Queue size,
- Multiple queues,
- Job dependency (chaining logic),
- Web page for real time monitoring and filtering,
- Command output in job detail (web page),
- Command statistics.