# How to execute a Symfony command as cron job?

Tags: php, linux, cron, symfony

I have this simple command in symfony :

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class AuctionEndCommand extends Command
{
protected function configure()
{
    error_log(print_r('test',true), 3, "/tmp/error.log");

    $this->setName('desktop:auction_end')->setDescription('Execute when auction is end.')->setHelp("Identify winners for auctions");
}
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{

    // outputs multiple lines to the console (adding "\n" at the end of each line)
    $output->writeln([
        'User Creator',
        '============',
        '',
    ]);

    // outputs a message followed by a "\n"
    $output->writeln('Whoa!');

    // outputs a message without adding a "\n" at the end of the line
    $output->write('You are about to ');
    $output->write('create a user.');
}
}
```

Now when I execute : `/var/www/myProject/bin/console desktop:auction_end` this command works fine. But when I try to execute as a cron in linux this script doesn't start :

In linux as sudo I did :
`nano crontab -e`, and the cron :

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/myProject/bin/console desktop:auction_end > /dev/null`

What I'm doing wrong, can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: What linux distrubution are you using/

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: Cron job has `/usr/bin/php` and regular command doesn't :-?

Comment: sudo crontab -e -u www-data to configure the tasks as the www-data user. This can prevent file permissions errors. And I would specify the environment with --env=prod if it is a production environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best practice how to schedule symfony2 action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518744/best-practice-how-to-schedule-symfony2-action)

Answer (score 5):

I can keep it very short. You will need to use PHP to execute the console.

```
* * * * * php -q /usr/bin/php /var/www/myProject/bin/console desktop:auction_end > /dev/null
```

Writing the output of a cron job that you are testing to a file will help you debug errors. All output is now lost in the void :)

```
* * * * * php -q /usr/bin/php /var/www/myProject/bin/console desktop:auction_end > /home/<user>/crons/auction_end.cron.txt
```

#### Edit

It might be that your `php` should be used as absolute path.

```
* * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/bin/console symfony:command
```

Or even by specifying the user to execute the command with:

```
* * * * *  root /usr/bin/php /path/to/bin/console command:to:execute
```

Also make sure that the root user has permission to execute files in your symfony project.

Comment: Is the file being created in your home directory? And does it contain any output?

Comment: The file is not created

Comment: 'not work :(' does not help me to help you. I will need more information.

Comment: the cron doesn't start, I don't have any logs in `/tmp/error.log`

Comment: Try executing a regular PHP file and see if that does work.

Comment: I created a file `test.php` in `/var/www/myProject` and I set up the cron...but this script doesn't start

Answer (score 1):

What user are you executing the cron as?
Symfony requires write access to ( depending on version ) app/cache && app/log(s) || var/cache && var/log(s) if the user you're executing the command as doesn't have write access to the directories you're trying to write to then your operation will fail.

A good way of fixing this would be to check the error logs, either in var/log(s) app/log(s) or check the apache2 error logs in /var/log/apache2/error.log I would guess one of these logs will contain a hint to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you run it as root, does that work:

```
* * * * * root php /var/www/myProject/bin/console desktop:auction_end > /dev/null
```

See if that works.