# Launch Symfony 4 function like a cronjob (as ADMIN)

Tags: function, symfony, cron, schedule

Is it possible (and what would be the most simple solution), to schedule (like a cronjob) the launch of symfony function ?

I would also need to secure it and launch then as an **SUPER_ADMIN_USER** of my website (using FOSUserBundle).

I saw that this is possible to integrate the unix cronjobs (but is there a solution inside symfony ?). Also I could not find information about the rights.

Comment: Try this: `https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best practice how to schedule symfony2 action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518744/best-practice-how-to-schedule-symfony2-action)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom command and add it to the crontab.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html